# Is there a way to change the background image in inspect element?

Tags: image, background, web-inspector

I haven't really been able to find anything that shows how to change a background image in inspect element.

My background image is set like the following:

[image]

How can I change this background image in inspect element?

Answer (score 5):

Paste the image link in like:

```
background-image: url(http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/someordinarygamers/images/a/a1/Sanic.gif/revision/latest?cb=20150624143958)
```

Then you need to uncheck the color of the background. It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to click the background-image property value, "url(/images/rate.jpg)", and change the url to the desired image.

Comment: I tried copy and pasting the image link like this background-image: url(http://image.jpg) and also like this background-image: url( image.jpg). Neither one seems to work.

Comment: @chiccaboom is `image.jpg` in the folder "images"? If so, it needs be `/images/image.jpg`. Wherever it is, you need to specify the path to it.

Comment: @River is correct. Make sure the url points to the correct location. Just an FYI, if you just type in 'image.jpg' it looks in the directory containing the css file currenty being modified. The Chrome console should show an error and tell you where its trying to locate the image.